# @OneToOne Hibernate with annotations. Can't properly save

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I can't make my foreign keys auto generate using hibernate and jpa with annotations. Everything seems ok, The entries are saved in database. All the date come from one form which, when submited creates an User object with ModelAttribute and then saves it in Database.
Here are my beans. Anything else i should add ?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="adress")
public class Adress implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="adress_id")
private Integer adressId;
@NotBlank(message="The city must be completed")
@Column(name="city")
@Size(min=5,max=30)
private String city;
@NotBlank(message="The street must be completed")
@Column(name="street")
@Size(min=5,max=30)
private String street;
@NotNull(message="The street number must be completed")
@NumberFormat
@Column(name="street_no")
private Integer streetNo;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private User user;}
```

and the other one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name="user_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer userId;
@NotBlank(message="Username can't be blank")
@Size(min=5,max=30)
@Column(name="username")
private String username;
@NotBlank(message="Password field can't be blank")
@Size(min=5,max=30)
@Column(name="password")
private String password;
@NumberFormat
@NotNull(message="Age field must not be blank")
@Column(name="age")
private Integer age;
@Column(name="message")
@Size(min=0,max=100)
private String message;
@Column(name="date")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/mm/yyyy")
private Date dateCreated;
@OneToOne(mappedBy="user",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Adress adress;
```

+getters and setters for them

```
public void save(T entity){
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(entity);
}
```

Comment: What does 'foreign keys auto generate' this mean? Do you want Hibernate to automatically generate tables for you? If yes, post your config. If you think stuff is not getting saved, post your DAO classes.

Comment: it means that i have a form that saves an user object and the adress in the user object in 2 tables in my database, but when i try to load the user after that from the database the adress field for the resulted object is null

Comment: U expect people to help for saving...yet there is no dao code...

Comment: here you go.. i can't imagine how this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly and you're trying to get Hibernate to set the foreign key on your related record this might help. Try getting rid of mappedBy and instead specify the JoinColumn. This works for me on a one to many:

The order:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`order`")
public class Order implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

// Order columns...

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
private Set<Item> items;

}
```

The item:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

// Item columns...

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private Order order;

}
```

Comment: it wasn't exactly what i needed but helped me anyway. thanks

Answer (score 0):

in adress class

```
 @OneToOne(mappedBy="adress")
private User user;
```

and in user class

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER,optional=false)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Adress adress;
```